# virtualbox in Ubuntu host no internet connection

Tags: 12.10, virtualbox, internet

My hair is in fire trying to make Internet connection work in guest OS.

I have Ubuntu 12.10 machine with VirtualBox 4.1.18 installed from Ubuntu Software Center

I set PC-BSD and FreeBSD to work as GuestOS

Now both GuestOS have no internet connection. I have tried different methods like:

`sudo apt-get install dnsmasq` and changed the `/etc/dnsmasq.d/network-manager` config to add `except-interface=lo` which blocked all of my internet connections.

I also added `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4` to `/etc/network/interfaces` and restart the `network-manager`.

Finally I did `VBoxManage modifyvm "PC-BSD" --natdnshostresolver1 on` and `VBoxManage modifyvm "PC-BSD" --natdnshostresolver1 on` but to no avail.

I have already tried `NAT` and different options in `Bridged` too

I still don't have internet connection in GuestOS, is there anyway I can fix this ? As far as I think the problem is in Ubuntu 12.10 for not sharing the internet, but I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After trying this and that, I fixed the problem as follows.

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

I commented out `auto lo` and added `auto eth0`. After that I did

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Now networking works in all VirtualBox guest OSes.

I don't know how this works, but in my Kubuntu 12.04 the network interfaces was set to `eth0`, so, I thought of giving it a try, and it works.

Edit:

As per `jdthood` suggestion, I had to put back the `lo` for network manager to work properly. After few days when I restart my computer, it started saying `Could not detect network` and I uncommented out `lo`, so, now I have both

> auth lo
>   auth eth0

and everything is working fine.

Comment: If that fixed it then the problem was the missing `auto eth0`. You should put the `auto lo` back, though. The `lo` interface is necessary and should be brought up automatically at boot.

Comment: If your `eth0` was not enabled previously, then how did you have internet access at all from the host? As I mentioned in my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/267868/134479), **IF** your host has normal internet connectivity, you need to do nothing but configure a NAT interface.

Comment: @zwets the host had normal internet connection (wireless) and but internet was not working in Guest. When I changed it to `eth0` suddenly everything is working.

Comment: @jdthood I don't understand what is with `lo` but certainly it look like it was blocking internet connection to pass to Guest. I use wireless network and everything is working perfectly even after reboot. I really don't know why is `eth0` or `lo` needed but I don't have internet connection problem now. Thanks for formatting the answer, I will check about network in ubuntu in details

Answer (score 0):

I am running VBox 4.2.8 in Ubuntu 12.10 with several guests (FreeBSD, Windows 7, Windows Server 2012) and use Bridged Mode, Deny Promiscuous in the network settings for VBox.  Everything just works OOB.  However, I have forgot to click the "Cable Connected" setting in the past and driven myself up a wall looking too deeply into the issue.  So make sure "Cable Connected" is ticked in network settings for your Guest in VBox.

I have never needed to do nat dns resolver on my Guests, so just manage all that within your network settings in PC-BSD.

http://wiki.pcbsd.org/index.php/Network_Configuration

Hope this helps.

Comment: the cable connected is on, I have tried both NAT and bridged... IDK what's wrong... I even reinstalled virtualbox, but no internet connection

Answer (score 0):

If your (Ubuntu) host has normal internet connectivity, and you create a virtual network card for a guest based on the default NAT configuration, then you are done at the host end. From this point on, VirtualBox (*not* Ubuntu) handles the traffic from the guest out to the network. As far as Ubuntu is concerned, VirtualBox is just another application using the network. It's no different from e.g. Firefox.

The NAT-ting, DHCP-ing and communicating with the guest is purely VirtualBox's business. Assuming VirtualBox works, what this means is that you'll need to solve this issue at the BSD end. The BSD experts are [right next door](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bsd).

Comment: I don't think its BSD problem, neither I am saying its Virtualbox problem... the Problem is in Ubuntu 12.10 IMO. I have Kubuntu 12.04 on other machine and I run PC-BSD, FreeBSD, Fedora and OpenSUSE without any internet problem. They are all using default NAT settings... That pc is quiet old and often runs out of memory while using virtualbox.