# Cannot connect to internet running Ubuntu 14.04 using VirtualBox on my MSI GT60 - Windows 8.1 x64

Tags: networking, virtualbox, windows-8, virtualbox-networking, msi

I'm unsure if I am asking this question in the right place so please refer me elsewhere if necessary. I installed VirtualBox v 4.3.2 on my MSI GT60 running Windows 8.1 x64 a bit ago and created a VM for an Ubuntu 14.04 OS. I am struggling to get internet connectivity after trying multiple network configurations in my virtual box manager. I have tried multiple adapter types and multiple network adapter attachements (NAT & bridged).  I have no idea where to even start to get this to work or begin diagnosing the issue.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

~ Max

Comment: possible duplicate of [virtualbox in Ubuntu host no internet connection](http://askubuntu.com/questions/267846/virtualbox-in-ubuntu-host-no-internet-connection)

Comment: I don't think so. The solution suggested in the linked thread does not work for me.

Comment: Your description of the problem is too generic! Start looking for possible problems.
First check your Firewall settings in Windows (including Windows Firewall), then research what kind of adapter settings you want for the virtual machine and config them (trying all possibilities usually dosn't help). I guess NAT should be good.
Check the network adapters in Windows: Are they up and running? Can you see packets going through?
Finally check your whole network setup in Ubuntu: Are the network adapters up an running, can you get an ip, etc pp.
If you find something strange you can google/ask about

Answer (score 1):

I was also having connectivity issues on Ubuntu installed on Virtual Box on my Windows 8.1.
I was going crazy as none of the solutions (on this forum and others) worked for me.
Out of the blue, I decided to uninstall Anti-Virus installed on Windows and restarted it. The next time I opened the same VM with Ubuntu, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and solved by:

- Turn off my Outpost firewall
- Turn off Windows.Defender
- In virtual machine settings - Network - Change from NAT to Bridged Adapter